# Nontrivial intersection when counting elements

Tags: group-theory

I think I have some problems in understanding here. I read a lot of questions about this subject but couldn't find a specific answer.

In an exercise from our class we have to count elements for a group of order $2pq$, where $2<p<q$ and the assumptions $q+1=2p$ and that there is more than one q-Sylow. So clearly, there are $q+1$ $q$-Sylows. But now we're supposed to just count $(q+1)(q-1)$ distinct elements, such that we can deduce that there is only one $p$-Sylow.

> How can we know that there are no nontrivial intersection between q-Sylows?

Comment: I suppose $q$ is prime, and the Sylow $q$-groups all have $q$ elements, so their intersection is either $1$-element (trivial) or $q$-element (in which case they coincide).

Comment: Oh, because if there was an intersection of say $q-x$ elements, then there was a subgroup of order $q-x$ and then $(q-x)$ must divide $q$, which is not possible.

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can't be subgroup of order $q^2$ (or any higher power), since otherwise $q^2 | 2pq$ and so $q|2p$. Because $q$ is prime and not $2$, it must divide $p$. But this is a contradiction, since $p<q$.

Hence the $q$-Sylows must be subroups of order $q$. But these are cyclic groups of prime order, so the only subgroups of them are trivial. The intersection of two subgroups is again a subgroup. Hence, the intersections must be trivial.